# What is the best way to determine whether a cluster is dense or sparse?

Tags: clustering, sparse

I tried using sum of distance from the center to every point. It did not perform well. Basically if I was given a part of either of these clusters, using this measure I want to be able to determine to which cluster it might belong. [image]

Is there any other measure I can use for determining the sparsity of the cluster?

Comment: Did you determine that there are exactly two clusters?

Comment: This was synthetic data. So i actually generated the two clusters. So, yes.

Comment: Consider using kernel density estimation.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Can i use KDE to quantitatively measure it? I can use KDE with a contour or a surface plot to visually observe it, but i want to be able to measure something quantitatively.

Comment: KDE is the standard measure for density...